# Is there a way to change a lua function to nil from C++ like changefunction(thefunction) and it goes to nil when called

Tags: c++, lua

so basically i want to add a lua function to my lua sandbox that has the ability to change other functions to nil like changefunction(func) and it will output an error for calling a nil value, example being:

```
changefunction(random); print(random()) --[[ goes to nil and errors ]] --
```

i have figured out how to do it by putting the functions name in the changefunction, Ex being changefunction("random"), it will search _G for the function. But the problem i run into is changing functions located in tables that arent _G.

any way to do this with having to use a string and being able to access any function in the lua sandbox?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: Isn't this the same as doing `myFunc = nil` or `myTable.myFunc = nil`? I don't think a function would help with that.

Comment: Using it to change functions globally and acrossed all lua files, because i have done func = nil and it didnt change it for all lua files so i wanted to just speed up the proccess by adding 1 function to do it all at once.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what's happening. You say that it works for global functions, so I don't know what you mean by "it didnt change it for all lua files".

Comment: Why is it tagged in `c++` though?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
-- Forward declaration for mutual recursion.
local changefunction

local function searchNewTable(t, f, visited)
  if type(t) == 'table' and not visited[t] then
    changefunction(t, f, visited)
  end
end

function changefunction(t, f, visited)
  -- Track circular references, so we don't get an infinite loop.
  visited = visited or {}
  visited[t] = true

  -- Search all of t.
  for k, v in pairs(t) do
    if k == f or v == f then
      -- Found it.
      t[k] = nil
    else
      -- Search every key and value for subtables.
      searchNewTable(k, f, visited)
      searchNewTable(v, f, visited)
    end
  end
end

changefunction(_G, random)
```

Note that this algorithm works the same regardless of whether or not the value you're removing is a function.

I highly recommend that `changefunction` takes a table argument for the table that you want to eliminate the value from. This is because some tables that contain the value might be in local variables, and therefore not reachable from `_G`. You'll have to call `changefunction` for each of those "master" tables.